# Handle the KeyDown Event when ALT+KEY is Pressed

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard, user-input

How do you handle a `KeyDown` event when the ALT key is pressed simultaneously with another key in .NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the code that finally Works

```
if (e.KeyCode >= Keys.A && e.KeyCode <= Keys.Z &&  e.Alt){
     //Do SomeThing
}
```

Comment: how will your spanish and french users like this?

Comment: Do the special characters in non-English languages (e.g ê) fall between key codes A-Z? I think the answer is no, but not certain. Sorry to bump an old post but I just stumbled upon it.

Comment: You mean English people don't use digit and punctuation? Seriously, this answer is not correct - almost every other are.

Answer (score 8):

The [KeyEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs_members.aspx) class defines several properties for key modifiers - [Alt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.alt.aspx) is one of them and will evaluate to `true` if the alt key is pressed.

Answer (score 5):

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Alt && e.KeyData != (Keys.RButton | Keys.ShiftKey | Keys.Alt))
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
   private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
   {
        if (e.Alt)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            // ,,,
        }
    }
```

Comment: The problem is that I get only the Alt key not the Key press with the ALT

Comment: @Jedi, you're supposed to get (separate) events for both.

Answer (score 0):

I capture the alt and down or up arrow key to increment the value of a numericUpDown control.  (I use the alt key + down/up key because this form also has a datagridview and I want down/up keys to act normally on that control.)

```
    private void frmAlzCalEdit_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Alt && e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
        {
            if (nudAlz.Value > nudAlz.Minimum) nudAlz.Value--;

        }
        if (e.Alt && e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
        {
            if (nudAlz.Value < nudAlz.Maximum) nudAlz.Value++;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a KeyUp event for your Form or use a library like I did to get a GlobalHook so you can press these keys outside the form.

Example:

```
 private void m_KeyboardHooks_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
                {
                    if ( e.KeyCode == Keys.Alt || e.KeyCode == Keys.X)
                    {     


                    }
                }
```