# How to display only my application forms when pressing Key1 + Key2, just like Alt + Tab does in Windows?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, alt-tab

My application has several forms. 
What I want to do is to be able to switch between them (and **only** between them) using a pair of predefined keys (say Keys.A + Keys.B), just like **ALT + TAB** does for Windows (windows are shown in foreground).
I tried getting the list of forms and then programmatically call Alt + Tab, but, as expected, this allows to switch between all open windows and not only the ones belonging to the application.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146970/handle-the-keydown-event-when-altkey-is-press

Comment: [Here is a similar topic][1]. Good luck! ;)


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346689/how-do-i-trap-windows-key-alttab-ctrlaltdelete-in-c

Comment: @UriY this shows only how to catch the event, and is not what I was looking for

Comment: @DareDevil73 how is this similar? I don't need to trap these keys, I need to copy and modify the behavior of Alt + Tab

Comment: Is it an MDI application? Strg-Tab is the standard for those.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement `IMessageFilter` and add it to your `Application`, then globally process the messages of your application.

Here is how you do that.

```
public class MessageFilter : IMessageFilter
{
    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        switch ((WindowsMessage)m.Msg)
        {
            case WindowsMessage.WM_KEYDOWN:
            case WindowsMessage.WM_SYSKEYDOWN:
                {
                    if (((int)m.WParam | ((int)Control.ModifierKeys)) != 0)
                    {
                        Keys keyData = (Keys)(int)m.WParam;

                        var activeForm = Form.ActiveForm;
                        var forms = Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>().Where(x => x.Visible).ToArray();
                        int active = Array.IndexOf(forms, activeForm);
                        if (keyData == Keys.A)
                        {
                            int next = (active + 1)%forms.Length;
                            forms[next].Activate();//Activate next
                        }
                        else if (keyData == Keys.B)
                        {
                            int prev = (active - 1) % forms.Length;
                            forms[prev].Activate();//Activate previous
                        }

                    break;
                }
        }

        return false;
    }
}

class MainForm : Form
{
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.AddMessageFilter(new MessageFilter());
    }
}
```

You can find [WindowsMessage](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2171/Windows-Message-ID-constants) enumeration here.

Comment: This only switches between the application forms, which is good. But the switch behavior must be identical to that of alt + tab on Windows (all application windows must be visible in foreground and the users should be able to selected the one he wants)

Comment: @mirelvlad Well that requires additional code, you can create a form with number of picture boxes which displays a thumbnail of displayed forms. Then show that to user, let him select what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple windows (forms) opened and they have normal caption or belong to MDI, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> is a standard shortcut to switch between them.

Otherwise, making a hotkey, to switch between forms is pretty trivial task:

- all forms have to have `KeyPreview = true` and `KeyDown` | `KeyUp` event;
- all forms instances have to be accessible (one possibility is `Application.OpenForms`);
- when hotkey is pressed, find *next* / *previous* window and make it active.

Comment: What I actually need is the switch behavior. It must be identical to that of alt + tab on Windows (all application windows must be visible in foreground and the users should be able to selected the one he wants)

Comment: @Sinatr You probably missed to see my answer, I posted a working sample of how to do that. but what OP asking is a lot to answer in SO :p

Comment: @Sinatr your solution only solves the switch between the windows. What I am mostly interested in is the manner in which I could display them just as Windows does with alt + tab

Comment: @mirelvlad, I got it, but there are no *easy* solution for that. You could implement *switch panel* by yourself, but if you want it to be a part of explorer (thinking about *Aero* 3d), then well, I pass out ^^.

Comment: @Sinatr I am working on it (debugging the alt + tab source code) and I will post the answer once I have it. Thanks for your help!